# loop and condition in ajax not correct

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, split

responseText like "insert-90RS252,insert-90RS262,insert-90RS232"

```
   function(responseText) {
       var res = responseText.split(",");
       for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
         var res2 = res[i].split("-");
         if (res2[0] === "insert") {
           alert(res2[0] + i);
         }

       }
     }
```

When alert:
insert1 and insert2
Not begin for step 0.Please help.

Comment: I cannot understand the question clearly.

Comment: i want to split ajax response.Then if  res equal insert then alert. When i alert it begin from 1 step not 0.res.length=3 but it alert 2 time

Answer (score 0):

`if(res2[0]==="insert")` should be `if(res2[1]==="insert")` because 'insert' will be the second element in res2 array.

Comment: Sorry. responseText like insert-90RS252,insert-90RS262,insert-90RS232

Comment: If you want to alert instead of logging to console you'll need to create a temporary string and add values to it during the loop and then alert it after the loop ends. I will update the codepen.

Comment: Your code is working. But i use it in ajax response.But it doesn`t work

Comment: Is the responseText coming from an ajax call? In that case make sure you are running the code in the callback so it runs after the request completes.

Comment: Yes. from ajax. when i alert(res2[0] + i) with condition it works true. But in condition it begin from second step

Comment: which condition? And what do you mean by 'it starts from second step'? maybe you could elaborate the question a bit more so it is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

It is Working....

```js
var Text = "insert-90RS252,insert-90RS262,insert-90RS232";

   
var res = Text.split(",");
for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
 var res2 = res[i].split("-");
  if (res2[0].trim() === "insert") {
    alert(res2[0] + i);
   }

}
```